# Forbid joi object in nested object

Tags: typescript, joi

I'm struggling with one validation using Joi and Typescript. I need to get rid of a key and it might be recursive.

```
const rootWhereSchema = Joi.object()
  .keys({
    companyId: Joi.any().forbidden(),
  })
  .pattern(/^\w+$/, [
    ...primitivesSchema,
    nullSchema,
    conditionSchema,
    Joi.array().items(Joi.link('#rootWhereSchema')).forbidden(),
  ])
  .id('rootWhereSchema');

const whereSchema = [rootWhereSchema, Joi.array().items(rootWhereSchema)];

export const querySchema = Joi.object<any, false, QuerySchema>({
  where: [whereSchema]
});
```

When I validate with the following pattern it will fail

```
where={"companyId":"<someId>"}
```

BUT when I nest the object it's not working

```
where={"company":{ "companyId": "<someId>"}}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?